# Ansible - How to print out this list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have this output from Windows auditpol.

I have difficulty to figure out how to print a certain output from the var *query*.

```
  - name: check audit
    win_command: auditpol /get /subcategory:{{ item }}
    with_items:
      - '"{{policy}}"'
    register:
      query
  - debug: var=query.results

ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
    "query.results": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "auditpol /get /subcategory:\"Other System Events\"",
            "delta": "0:00:00.171888",
            "end": "2022-11-24 06:04:11.903563",
            "failed": false,
            "item": "\"Other System Events\"",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2022-11-24 06:04:11.731675",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "System audit policy\r\r\nCategory/Subcategory                      Setting\r\nSystem\r\n  Other System Events                     No Auditing\r\r\n",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "System audit policy",
                "",
                "Category/Subcategory                      Setting",
                "System",
                "  Other System Events                     No Auditing",
                ""
            ]
        }
    ]
}

  - debug: msg="{{ query.results | type_debug }}"
ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
    "msg": "dict"
}

  - debug: msg="{{ query | type_debug }}"
ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
    "msg": "list"
}
```

How do I print out one of the list, i.e. stdout_lines?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://pythonexamples.org/python-list-of-dictionaries/

```
  - debug: var=query.results[0]['stdout_lines']
ok: [ipcprdixn201] => {
    "query.results[0]['stdout_lines']": [
        "System audit policy",
        "",
        "Category/Subcategory                      Setting",
        "System",
        "  Other System Events                     No Auditing",
        ""
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why would you mix two syntaxes? Either use `query.results.0.stdout_lines` or use `query['results'][0]['stdout_lines']`